# AHK with command ^!ENTER::Send {Media_Play_Pause} doesn't work in Windows 11

Tags: autohotkey

I want to be able to play and stop a Youtube Video using Auto Hot Key while I am using the Vs Code editor, without the need to stop and play the video with the mouse. That will save some time.Any help would be appreciated.

I can rewind back and forth, but I want to be able to play/pause it as well.

**^!ENTER::Send {Media_Play_Pause}** ( Only this command does Not work )

So far I have this script:

```
#SingleInstance, Force 
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 
SetBatchLines, -1 
SetWinDelay, -1

^!ENTER::Send {Media_Play_Pause} ; ( Only this command does Not work )

^!Left:: 
    WinGet, Current_Window, ID, A 
    WinActivate, - YouTube 
    ControlGetPos, conX, conY, , , ChromeRenderWidgetHostHWD1 
    ControlClick,, A,,,, % " X" (conX+1) " Y" (conY+1) 
    ControlSend, , {Left 3}, A 
    WinActivate, % "AHK_ID" Current_Window 
return

^!Right:: 
    WinGet, Current_Window, ID, A 
    WinActivate, - YouTube 
    ControlGetPos, conX, conY, , , ChromeRenderWidgetHostHWD1 
    ControlClick,, A,,,, % " X" (conX+1) " Y" (conY+1) 
    ControlSend, , {Right 3}, A 
    WinActivate, % "AHK_ID" Current_Window 
return
```

Comment: Which AutoHotkey version are you running?

Comment: Are the key strokes for youtub not  j=rewind, L=forward, k=pause/play(or spacebar), f=fullscreen toggle